# SOAP Windows phone 7 paypal

Tags: windows-phone-7, soap, paypal

who's worked with paypal soap api in windows phone 7?
Give me an example please

Answer (score 2):

so go for NVP ? https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/index.html
as far as I understood, you won't need SSL here

Answer (score 0):

PayPal have a fairly thorough set of documentation here: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code